# WebStorm debug node+babel takes too much time

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, webstorm, babeljs

When I'm trying to debug Node.js code, which uses babel for the last JS features, using WebStrom debugger, it takes too much time. I think debugger does not go into other files except file with babel-register.

`index.js` file is

```
require('babel-register');
console.log("Hello world");
```

Here are my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you increased the allowable memory of WebStorm? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tuning-the-ide.html

Comment: @SyntaxRules, I upgraded WebStrom to 2018.3 AEP and problem solves